# How can I watch more than one QFuture?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

The `QFutureWatcher` class emits the signal `finished()` when the `QFuture` it is watching has finished.
How can I watch more than one `QFuture`?
I am running two threads in parallel using `QtConcurrent::run()` and would like to get a signal when both threads have finished.

Comment: Did one of the answers work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach the problem like this:

1. Create as many `QFutureWatcher`s as needed
2. Add all `QFutureWatcher`s to a list, resp. vector, e.g. `m_futureWatchers`:

   ```
    m_futureWatchers.append(futureWatcher);
   ```
3. Connect the `QFutureWatcher::finished` signals to the same slot, e.g. `handleFinished`:

   ```
    connect(futureWatcher, &QFutureWatcher<int>::finished, this, MyClass::handleFinished);
   ```
4. In the `handleFinished` slot check `QFutureWatcher::isFinished` and react accordingly:

   ```
    bool allAreFinished = true;

    for (auto *futureWatcher : m_futureWatchers)
        allAreFinished &= futureWatcher->isFinished();

    if (allAreFinished) {
        // doSomething
    }
   ```

**Note:** For only two future watchers, it might be easier to have two member variables, e.g. `m_futureWatcher1` and `m_futureWatcher1`, instead of a list, and check them in the `handleFinished` slot like this:

```
if (m_futureWatcher1->isFinished() && m_futureWatcher2->isFinished) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use 3rd party [AsyncFuture](https://github.com/benlau/asyncfuture) library for Qt:

Combine multiple futures with different type into a single future object:

```
/* Combine multiple futures with different type into a single future */

QFuture<QImage> f1 = QtConcurrent::run(readImage, QString("image.jpg"));

QFuture<void> f2 = observe(timer, &QTimer::timeout).future();

QFuture<QImage> result = (combine() << f1 << f2).subscribe([=](){
    // Read an image but do not return before timeout
    return f1.result();
}).future();

QCOMPARE(result.progressMaximum(), 2);
```